# How do I get the last evaluated expression in OCaml's toplevel?

Tags: ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, ocaml-toplevel

How do I refer to the last evaluated expression in OCaml's toplevel repl?

I.e. JavaScript uses `$_`, python uses `_`, and haskell ghci uses `it`.

Comment: SML's toplevel also uses `it`. Interesting that it's not there by default in OCaml REPLs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not implemented by the default `ocaml` REPL bundled with the compiler. With utop, there is an option to enable this behavior with the `-implicit-bindings` flag. With this settings, all anonymous bindings are named as `_0`,`_1`,`_2`,... .